# Will detected hallucinations trigger Widow Mines?

Tags: starcraft-2

The wiki says that detected hallucinations get the lowest attack priority by the AI, but is that high enough to trigger Widow Mines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sure is high enough to trigger the Widow mines. But like you say, the Widow mines goes for the highest priority, which is non-hallucinated units.

Bonus info:
You can attack with the Widow mine yourself. If you rather kill a Stalker, not a Zealot, simply attack click the Stalker, and the Widow mine will target the Stalker.
This move can be useful for defense and for a Widow mine mine-line drop.